# Android sharedpreferences Array

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an array in a shared preferences, and an array with values in my class in Android.

The thing is, I will generate a number that is equal to the index of my array in my class
and store that generated values to the array in my shared preferences without duplicate,

For example:

```
String array[] = {"can", "you", "help", "me"}

Random ran = new Random();
int x = ran.nextInt(4);

String generatedValue = array[x];
```

The generatedValue will be stored to array in my shared preference.

I have tried creating 120 keys cause I have 120 indexes in my array but it's not the proper way of storing it to the shared preferences.

Here is what I have done:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor edit1 = firstFile.edit();
edit1.putString("key1", "");
edit1.commit();
```

and so on and so forth

Comment: do you really need an array all the time?? is not one value enough throughout the entire application ?

Comment: If the array don't have **repeated** value, a value can be a key, and just call `putString(value, value)`.

Comment: yes I really need it, you know the concept of the game 4 pic 1 word? the game show all the pictures with the corresponding word without repetition. so I want to store the generated string in the sharedpreferences and generate another string not equal to strings that is stored in the sharedpreferences

Comment: @AlexChi I have 120 indexes in my array, so do you think it is advisable to create 120 keys in sharedpreferences?

Comment: Or you can use the index as a key to store it into `SharedPerferences`. `edit1.putString(String.valueOf(index), array[index]);`.

Comment: @AlexChi I will try this code, whatever the result I will inform you immediately, thank you so much for helping me

Comment: @AlexChi how can i retrieve those values that i have stored?

Comment: the codes you have given me, was not credible enough to solve my problem, by the way thank you so much for helping me